# Use jquery to make chat boxes float like facebook

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying a make a chat script like a facebook, but my problem is when i delete a chat box , there place left empty, what i want is for example i have 3 chat boxes , so when i delete the first one i want the second one replace the first one and the third one replace the second one and so on. 
this is how i create chat boxes:

```
function createChatBox(chatboxtitle,minimizeChatBox) {
    if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).length > 0) {
        if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display','block');
            restructureChatBoxes();
        }
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();
        return;
    }

    $(" <div />" ).attr("id","chatbox_"+chatboxtitle)
    .addClass("chatbox")
    .html('<div class="chatboxhead" onclick="javascript:toggleChatBoxGrowth(\''+chatboxtitle+'\')"><div class="chatboxtitle">'+chatboxtitle+'</div><div class="chatboxoptions"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:closeChatBox(\''+chatboxtitle+'\')">X</a></div><br clear="all"/></div><div class="chatboxcontent"></div><div class="chatboxinput"><textarea class="chatboxtextarea" onkeydown="javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey(event,this,\''+chatboxtitle+'\');"></textarea></div>')
    .appendTo($( "#bottom" ));                        // where to add chat boxes

    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('bottom', '0px'); // chat box position

    chatBoxeslength = 0;

    for (x in chatBoxes) {
        if ($("#chatbox_"+chatBoxes[x]).css('display') != 'none') {
            chatBoxeslength++;
        }
    }

    if (chatBoxeslength == 0) {
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('left', '0px'); // to display chat box left
    } else {
        width = (chatBoxeslength)*(218.3+7)+0;
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('left', width+'px'); //boxes float to the left
    }

    chatBoxes.push(chatboxtitle);

    if (minimizeChatBox == 1) {
        minimizedChatBoxes = new Array();

        if ($.cookie('chatbox_minimized')) {
            minimizedChatBoxes = $.cookie('chatbox_minimized').split(/\|/);
        }
        minimize = 0;
        for (j=0;j<minimizedChatBoxes.length;j++) {
            if (minimizedChatBoxes[j] == chatboxtitle) {
                minimize = 1;
            }
        }

        if (minimize == 1) {
            $('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle+' .chatboxcontent').css('display','none');
            $('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle+' .chatboxinput').css('display','none');
        }
    }

    chatboxFocus[chatboxtitle] = false;

    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").blur(function(){
        chatboxFocus[chatboxtitle] = false;
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").removeClass('chatboxtextareaselected');

    }).focus(function(){
        chatboxFocus[chatboxtitle] = true;
        newMessages[chatboxtitle] = false;
        $('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle+' .chatboxhead').removeClass('chatboxblink');
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").addClass('chatboxtextareaselected');
    });

    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).click(function() {
        if ($('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle+' .chatboxcontent').css('display') != 'none') {
            $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();
        }
    });

    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).show();}
```

and this is the function that i want to manipulate to make the trick work :

```
function closeChatBox(chatboxtitle) {
    $('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle).css('display','none');
    restructureChatBoxes();
    $.post("chat.php?action=closechat", { chatbox: chatboxtitle} , function(data){  
    });}
```

Comment: please make a example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Hushme i don't know how to get the url in jsfiddle.net

Comment: save your jsfiddle then click 'share'